# Proper way to map ObjectId to String in DTO in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-websocket

I am working with Spring WebSocket. I have this DTO of the `Message`

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MessageDto {

    private ObjectId messageId;
    private ObjectId chatId;
}
```

When I send this DTO as response, `ObjectId` fields in DTO maps like this:

[image]

How can I map `ObjectId` field into `String` like `62790c02513ad11442eec6d7`?

Comment: [ObjectId.toString()?](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/)

Comment: @1sina1 DTO maps automatically by Spring. I am looking for a proper way to create a mapper that Spring can use.

Comment: You have your answer 'DTO maps automatically by Spring', so define messageId and chatId as String and it will map ObjectId to a String automatically too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring uses `Jackson` to map objects to `JSON`, so the proper way to map `ObjectId` field in a object is to configure `Jackson` serializers.

Create a serializer class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ObjectIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ObjectId> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(ObjectId id, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(id == null ? null : id.toString());
    }
}
```

And then specify the serializer in a DTO class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MessageDto {

    @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdSerializer.class)
    private ObjectId messageId;
    @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdSerializer.class)
    private ObjectId chatId;
}
```

In conclusion, the `ObjectId` field of the `MessageDto` object will be serialized like a string in `JSON`

Of course, there is a problem to deserialize `JSON` to an object. There are `JsonDeserializer<>` and `@JsonDeserialize` to solve this problem. But there (mapping `ObjectId` class field) deserializer is useless, because `ObjectId` already have a constructor, that receives a `String` parameter, so `Jackson` will use it.